# Issue AngularJS version upgrade ContactForm

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i made a contact form for my homepage and added it.
Alright it works.

But i want to use other stuff which is not work fine with AngularJS under Version 1.3.0.
I upgraded the angular Js version from `1.2.0` to `1.5.0`.

After upgrading, click on button "type=submit" the page will be refresh.

I added the two versions on plunker:

---

Angular JS Version [1.2.0](https://plnkr.co/edit/aFL2guMKu1V4aEI5TSCG?p=preview)

### After click on Send Message, the User will show if there are some problems with input.

---

Angular JS Version [1.5.0](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tk5QXcWB1yrjCdXmQHRY?p=preview)

### After click on Send Message, the site is refreshed with an error.

I only changed the version. 
Version greater than 1.3.0 will refresh the page, sometimes with an error.

---

What i have to change in my code, so the site will not be refresh after click on that button, rather show me the false input values, like in with angular version 1.1.5.

Have anybody an idea to fix that issue?
Or why it refresh the site after upgrading it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's not exactly clear from your description what your problem is.  However, you are using an *ancient* version of angular material (0.8.3) which isn't even supported (0.9.0 is the first supported version, 1.0.5 is the latest).  Also, angular 1.1.5 is deprecated as well (1.2.0 is minimum supported), and the combination of angular 1.1.5 plus material was never supported, so results from this combination are suspect.  Comparing this to anything would not be reasonable.

Comment: also, I cannot reproduce a page refresh with your 1.5.0 sample plunker.

Comment: thanks for answering ... it don't won't to have a page refresh. Okay, when i delete the angular material part it will be clear. When i have angularjs version 1.1.5 or 1.2.0 or 1.2.15 the contact form will work fine, it give the issue of the input back, like in the plunker version. this is what the code has to do. But when i change the version of angular js to 1.3.0 or 1.4.0 or something over version 1.3.0 the same code give error back. So nothing is changed, only the version of angular js and the code don't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  the example you provided does not refresh, and it is not supposed to.

Comment: the code should NOT refresh. When you start the code with the low version. After click on Send Message, a red box is shown. That is what i want to have at angular version 1.5.0. But at the higher version, the same code don't show me the red box, rather it refresh and give an error back. So my problem is. The same Code, but with different Angular Versions it will not work again. I adapted the code in the plunker links

Comment: both examples operate exactly the same when I examine them.  Again, it's not really clear what you are trying to describe.  If I add code to the script.js under `if(contactForm.$valid){`, it executes correctly in both versions.  The button enables and disables identically in both versions.  If you have a problem, you aren't demonstrating it here.

Comment: After click on 'Send Message':

Comment: After click on 'Send Message': With version 1.2.0 i got this: https://pl.vc/44eki ... With Version 1.5.0 i got this: https://pl.vc/3hqju ... So Same Code, but with Version 1.5.0 the Code don't work again. That is the problem. The code works correct with version 1.2.0 but not with 1.5.0.  Sorry for describing. I mean if nothing is typed in the areas. Only open it, and click on Send Message. Don't type anything in like name or email. Let all empty, and click on Send Message. Maybe now it will be clear ^^ Sorry

Comment: so these are videos of my issue: https://youtu.be/aYH1gjPnH6A that ist with Version 1.2.0 when i type in something and click on send message, nothing happens. Good, its working, after type in all the input right, then click Send message, it will be good.  BUT at Version 1.5.0 : https://youtu.be/Ywyse9tBKjI When i click on Send Message, the page will be refresh, after type in only one thing, and click on Send Messagen, the input is removed and the page refreshed. But i want to have it like with version 1.2.0. NO refreshing. Its now clear what i mean?

Comment: so when you type in only one thing and send, with version 1.5.0 all inputs are removed and the page is reloaded. That is my problem

Comment: I see that this is what is occurring in the video you showed, but this **is not** what is occurring in the plunker samples you provided.  Something in your code is different from the examples you provided.

Comment: maybe it's different because of host it with localhost and on plunker ... it is the same code.

Comment: I fixed it. I implemented the code step by step, its the same code, but without any issue, don't know why but its fixed :) Thanks for helping. How can i close this topic?